# InvalidOperationException: Register the constraint type with 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.RouteOptions.ConstraintMap'

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Recently a change was made to our code and I'm stuck as far as how to fix it.  Originally we had the routes on our controllers set up as

```
[Route("api/v1/product/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
```

And this was modified to accomodate versioning as follows:

```
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/product/[controller]")]
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
```

And now the app is throwing the following error:

```
InvalidOperationException: The constraint reference 'apiVersion' could not be resolved to a type. Register the constraint type with 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.RouteOptions.ConstraintMap'.
```

The dev that implemented this is unavailable, so I'm looking for suggestions until they get back.  Seems to work fine in our dev environment but can't run it locally.  We're running .NET 6 and this is the startup code:

```
  if (enableSwagger)
  {
    services
    .AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
      c.SwaggerDoc(EngineExtensions.API_ENGINE_VERSION, new Microsoft.OpenApi.Models.OpenApiInfo { Title = EngineExtensions.API_ENGINE_NAME, Version = EngineExtensions.API_ENGINE_VERSION });
      c.CustomSchemaIds(type => type.FullName);
    });
  }
```

referencing this in appsettings

```
"api_engine_version": "v1",
```

Comment: What .Net version are you using and can you also share the part in Startup.cs where you configure API versioning?

Comment: This configuration is for Swagger, what you would really need is something like services.AddApiVersioning and services.AddVersionedApiExplorer methods. Can you somehow find them?

Comment: Looks like this is being configured in a shared library, I think this is the line doing it:

    public static string API_ENGINE_VERSION => System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()?.GetName().Version?.ToString() ??
                                               Configuration["api_engine_version"]?.Replace("\"", string.Empty, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

Comment: Still, it is only being used for Swagger documentation. Can you make a test in your development machine via Postman with and without the 2 methods I wrote in the attempted answer and check this against an endpoint, something that makes a get request, for example, like health check?

Comment: We are missing some kind of dependency at a upper level and this got handed off to a different team.  Thanks for the answers, I was out of my element here.

Comment: Hi, have you got any updates?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you are configuring versioning in Startup.cs. You should be using AddApiVersioning and AddVersionedApiExplorer extension methods of IServiceCollection (in ConfigureServices method). An example would be:

```
 services.AddApiVersioning(config =>
        {
            // Specify the default API Version as 1.0
            config.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1, 0);
            // Advertise the API versions supported for the particular endpoint (through 'api-supported-versions' response header which lists all available API versions for that endpoint)
            config.ReportApiVersions = true;
        });

        services.AddVersionedApiExplorer(setup =>
        {
            setup.GroupNameFormat = "'v'VV";
            setup.SubstituteApiVersionInUrl = true;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem.

You need to make sure that you are using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning.

Just add AddControllers() and AddApiVersioning() to Program.cs

Complete code：

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddApiVersioning();
```

Referenced links：

https://www.infoworld.com/article/3562355/how-to-use-api-versioning-in-aspnet-core.html